# Python's “//” operator wrongly treated as a comment (part 2)

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

SO's Google code prettify on python wrongly handles `//` (floor division) as a C-style comment, [as noted here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81906/pythons-operator-treated-as-a-comment), even when the question is tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python).

Here is a more recent example from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1567607/finding-substring):

```python
a[:len(a)//3*3]
```

Comment: How is March 6th 2011 "two years ago"?

Comment: Sorry, my tired brain misread _'edited Mar 6 at 20:08'_. Doh. Edited that out.

Answer (score -2):

Because Python is a "webby" language, and code snippets in those posts tend to contain a mixture of

- HTML
- CSS
- Python

The syntax highlighting mode for the all questions tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) is set to default, that is, infer.

If you wish to override it, you can add the following hint above a code block.

`<!-- language: lang-py -->`

Per https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: I was documenting the known issue; at first glance I thought 'WTF?'. This issue was known two years ago, I assume someone at SO already filed that bug with Google Prettify, is that not so?

Comment: I mean at first glance I couldn't understand what was happening and thought the highlighting was broken. Then I did some reading on meta and found this is a known issue. Thanks Jeff.

Comment: @smci oh wait, I see. let me edit.

Comment: Sorry, as balpha points out, the issue was noted 5 months ago, not 2 years.

Comment: Is it not better to associate [tag:html] with `lang-html`, [tag:css] with `lang-css`, and [tag:python] with `lang-py`, such that the [tag-based language selection](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting`) causes questions tagged with any combination of these tags to continue to use _default_, but single-tagged questions are specific?

Comment: Python is **not** a webby language. The number of Python posts that contain HTML or CSS are *minimal*.