# Manual specification of code block with <!-- language: python --> fails

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, tags

According to [the editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting):

> You can use either one of the supported prettify language codes, like lang-cpp or lang-sql, or you can specify a tag, and the syntax highlighting language associated with this tag will be used:
>
> ```
> <!-- language: c# -->
>
>     public static bool IsAwesome { get { return true; } }
> ```

However, in [this revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18270236/revisions), `<!-- language: python -->` fails, yet `<!-- language: lang-py -->` works. [python](/questions/tagged/python) is clearly a valid tag, so I'd expect both to work

This also would explain why questions tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python) do not automatically use python syntax highlighting

Comment: This is a duplicate. I can **feel** it.

Comment: [tag:python] is associated with the default highlighter, not `lang-py`, so this behaviour is expected. Now, I don't know *why* [tag:python] isn't associated with the `lang-py` highlighter, so that might be unintentional.

Comment: ...Or not, Jeff seems to classify it as a ["webby language"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97454), which means it gets the default highlighter.

Comment: @TimStone: I don't think I've seen a single python question with an HTML block in.

Comment: Yeah, you might be able to make a case for having the associated highlighter changed.

Comment: Python is so *not* a webby language. Jeff's assertion is way off the mark there.

Comment: Hey, I can change that! Interesting. But is there another problem that changing it away from the default causes? The whole syntax highlighting system is hopelessly broken.

Comment: @minitech: I am willing to find out! Change it, change it *NAUOW*!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Well, here we go!

Comment: This is certainly _not_ a dupe of the css-related one (stating that there [tag:css] is used together with either [tag:html] or [tag:javascript] and therefore shouldn't cause confusion) - what other tags are _usually_ used together with [tag:python] that justify not having it default to `lang-py`?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: Python-2.7, python-3.x, numpy, tkinter, to name but a few.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... "that justify _not_ having it default to `lang-py`"?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler: The tags `django`, `flask`, `zope`, `plone`, `web.py`, and `wsgi` perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't exhaustively search, but on a quick glimpse I could not spot any post containing non-python code under these tags which actually "deserves" the tag python

Comment: Exactly; I am puzzled by why Jeff thought Python was a webby language deserving of not having the `lang-py` language highlighter applied by default.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, so we agree - I somehow got the impression you were giving counterexamples there

Comment: The title of the question seems to be incorrectly auto-“corrected”. This smells of Microsoft Word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed it, as Python is really not a “web language”.

Let’s see what sort of horrible consequences arise… :(