# Expose syntaxes associated with tags on data.stackexchange

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, data-explorer, syntax-highlighting

Syntax highlighting is currently [inferred from the question's tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting). However, the links between tags and their syntax is seemingly arbitrary, with [some](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121816/147400) [languages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193495/147400) having no association.

While I know only moderators can change this setting, it would be nice if it could be displayed to other members of the community, be it on the tag wiki pages, or accessible through [data.stackexchange](https://data.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info would be good, since that is the page where the moderators set the syntax highlighting language for [tag:php].

Comment: What would be the advantage of knowing this information, considering you can't do anything useful with it?

Comment: +1 As a moderator on ja.so, I'd like to be able to look at which syntax highlighting option is applied to which tags on en.so and copy the settings over to ja.so.

Answer (score 3):

This is now available on sites that have the Prettify Markdown extension<sup>1</sup> enabled:

[image: Code language used at the bottom of tag info wiki]

Unfortunately this data is not (yet?) available in SEDE.

---

<sub>1. Despite the fact that the syntax highlighter is now [highlight.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353983/goodbye-prettify-hello-highlight-js-swapping-out-our-syntax-highlighter) in the API the markdown extension is still named [Prettify](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/sites?filter=!6Oe*uiLMit_n5)</sub>