# Question titles collapse "-​- " (double minus signs) to "— " (mdash)

Tags: support, title

`--` in a title is collapsed to `—`. This probably isn't so great if the title [contains `<!-- -->`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193495/147400) [or `x--`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13136724/102441).

Is this intended behavior?

---

Running this query on data.stackexchange (I don't claim to be good at SQL):

```
SELECT
    sum(case when Title LIKE '% -- %' then 1 else 0 end) AS [mdash],
    sum(case when Title LIKE '% <!-- %' then 1 else 0 end) AS [comment],
    sum(case when Title LIKE '%[a-z0-9]-- %' then 1 else 0 end) AS [decrement],
    sum(case when Title LIKE '% --[a-z0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) AS [increment],
    sum(case when (Title LIKE '%-- %' OR Title LIKE '%--- %')
              and Title NOT LIKE '% -- %'
              and Title NOT LIKE '% <!-- %'
              and Title NOT LIKE '%[a-z0-9]-- %'
              and Title NOT LIKE '% --[a-z0-9]%' then 1 else 0 end) AS [uncategorized] FROM Posts
```

I get the following results:

```
mdash comment decrement increment uncategorized
7665  34      368       1752      472
```

The vast majority of valid uses cases would be unaffected by Tim Stone's proposal

Comment: `<!-- -->` shouldn't be in titles. Titles should be descriptive about the problem, not include code snippets.

Comment: Yes, it’s intended behaviour. Yes, it’s stupid behaviour. It’s also silly inconsistent.

Comment: @MichaelIrigoyen: What if the question is about this bug? ;)

Comment: "Questions containing two dashes in the title collapses to an mdash"? I mean, why in the title did @Eric include `--` but spell out mdash? Titles should contain words, not code, IMO.

Comment: @Michael, [Manual specification of code block with <!— language: python --> fails](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193495/manual-specification-of-code-block-with-language-python-fails) seems like a fine title to me.

Comment: For one, the double dash is used for `--` operator

Comment: And, @Michael, so does [Why is i— faster than i++ in loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136724/why-is-i-faster-than-i-in-loops)...

Comment: What you all need — in my opinion — is a proper compose key…

Comment: Unless I'm seeing things, in the example Arjan showed the effect only occured with the first -- in the title.

Comment: Despite some legitimate uses, it seems a lot of time they are used for `[tag] --...` in titles.

Comment: @BillWoodger: Yep; see regex below.

Comment: @BillWoodger: That's because the other `--` is actually a `++`

Comment: Or you could add support for backtick quoted code.

Comment: As a note, I see "--" in all titles instead of an em dash on my phone's browser (BB10), confused me for a while because both looked identical in the title.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, although obviously it's not perfect in that it can't detect your intent when you actually mean to have double hyphens. Titles are modified based loosely on rules from [SmartyPants](http://daringfireball.net/projects/smartypants/), which include transforming `--` and `---` to `&mdash;` (—).

The regular expression used to do the replacement is just `---?(\s)`, which may be considered incorrect on the grounds that most style guides frown on putting spaces around en/em dashes…but given that the trailing space is in fact a requirement here, requiring a leading one might be a reasonable way to reduce incorrect conversions (validity of including code snippets in titles aside).

Comment: How about letting people type em dashes if they want em dashes?

Comment: I'm all for changing the regex to require a leading whitespace character

Comment: @minitech People using double minus signs as a pseudo em dash is likely a more common case than there being a legitimate reason to have them literally rendered in the title, with the notable programming-topic exceptions of having something like `--i` or `i--`, which tweaking the regex would fully address.

Comment: So do I retag this as a feature-request, or what?

Comment: @Eric You could, sure. I think Jeff's counterargument on that other post is a bit weak.

Comment: [The real problem is that you can’t escape it, though](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193593/160410)

Comment: @minitech: Sure, just surround it in quotes!

Comment: @Eric: But that’s yucky!

Comment: @minitech: Hey, you're referring to the literal string '--' - seems reasonable to quote it

Comment: @Eric: But then I wouldn’t be able to make an annoyed reference to this bug!

Comment: How about an escape way ?