# Quotation marks in titles are automatically rendered in `&ldquo;`/`&rdquo;` format even when posted using `&quot;` format

Tags: discussion, markdown

Quotation marks in titles are automatically rendered in `&ldquo;`/`&rdquo;` (“”) format even when posted using `&quot;` ("") format.

For an example of this we can look at this question: [What does <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e)

The title is rendered as:

> What's the difference if `<meta http-equiv=“X-UA-Compatible” content=“IE=edge”>` exists or not?

This is a direct copy and paste. It's worth noting at this point that this isn't valid HTML.

If we edit the question, we can see that the title is actually entered as:

> What's the difference if `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` exists or not?

This *is* valid HTML. Equally, this is how the link is rendered within this question.

Comment: I don't feel this is really a problem; it doesn't obscure the title, it is still very clear what the intent is here; and in most cases it will make the title look more appealing

Comment: @nijansen the problem is that users may simply copy a code snippet from a post's title assuming it may work. With the quotations rendered this way, it wouldn't.

Comment: Related: [Question titles collapse “-​- ” (double minus signs) to “— ” (mdash)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193572/question-titles-collapse-double-minus-signs-to-mdash)

Comment: [here's another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50683786/why-does-arrayin-i-give-different-results-in-java-8-and-java-10) where this clearly is an issue. Why would we want to do this in a coding site?

Comment: seems to be due to [smartypants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68844/fix-markdown-smartypants-in-question-titles)