# Python's “//” operator wrongly treated as a comment (part 3)

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

The closing reason for [Python's “//” operator wrongly treated as a comment (part 2)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97452/pythons-operator-wrongly-treated-as-a-comment-part-2) , *"Python is a webby language"*, [was refuted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97452/pythons-operator-wrongly-treated-as-a-comment-part-2#comment606466_97454) (by none other than [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/140890/martijn-pieters), one of the top Python experts at SO).

Statistics confirm this: as of 01.2015, [there are more than 400k questions with](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/269081/351473/) [python](/questions/tagged/python) on SO while [only less than 10k of them intersect with](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/269081/351474/) [html](/questions/tagged/html), [css](/questions/tagged/css) or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

<sub>(The queries linked count all other tags that contain those substrings, too. But it's safe to assume such tags typically relate to those languages as well.)</sub>

Comment: Yet questions tagged with Python use Python as the default language these days. Jeff's opinion has long since been overridden.

Comment: What exactly did you want to achieve with this post? There is nothing to fix here, nor do you actually state a question.

Comment: What do you mean, "there's nothing to fix"? There's still the syntax highlighting error to fix. This all was stated in the question I follow up.

Comment: If there are errors still with the Python syntax highlighter then that's a bug to be fixed by the Google Prettifier, not Stack Exchange. That's why the other post was duped to the [canonical syntax highlighter post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). Can you show me a sample post that *did not use `lang-py` automatically* even though it should and has `//` highlighted as a comment?

Comment: Highlighting is working just fine: [In Python, what is the difference between '/' and '//' when used for division?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/183853)

Comment: You mean, issues with an external library used at SE can't be discussed here? Then this should be stated explicitly. Linking to the generic SH post doesn't bring home anything close to such a message.

Comment: @MartijnPieters ... and is broken here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28236021/648265

Comment: The FAQ states explicitly that bugs in the parsing are to be filed with the Prettify project.

Comment: That question is tagged C and Python. In such cases no language highlighter is forced and the highlighter uses *guessing*. Edit the answer to use an explicit `<!-- language: lang-py -->` comment instead.

Comment: I tried to no effect (at least in the preview)

Comment: The preview has a delay; wait a little while after making changes and highlighting is applied. As for the multiple tags issue, see [Changes to syntax highlighting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72082): *If a question has two tags that both define specific languages, it uses default and lets prettify infer as it always has.*

Comment: I've added the comment (using `language-all` in this case).

Comment: I know the preview has a delay. The problem turned out to be, the comment was ignored if there was no blank line between it and the preceeding text. I'll file this as a bug instead.

Comment: No, that is by design, not a bug. That is how Markdown works.

Comment: Even if it's by design, the highlighting help doesn't mention this when describing the comment.

Comment: There is an outstanding bug with the Markdown help having removed significant newlines in the examples, IIRC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighting bug on Stack Overflow (using the default "guess" highlighting on python questions) has already been fixed; [the `python` tag there](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/python/info) defaults to `lang-py` now.

[The problem still occurs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) *if a question includes multiple language tags* (like both [python](/questions/tagged/python) and [c](/questions/tagged/c) tags) in which case, one needs to [state the code's language explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) to correctly highlight constructs that are interpreted differently between those.