# Document required blank line before language hint in Markdown help

Tags: feature-request, markdown, syntax-highlighting, help-center

As per [Python's “//” operator wrongly treated as a comment (part 3)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247840/pythons-operator-wrongly-treated-as-a-comment-part-3#comment812076_247840), there must be a blank line before a language hint — otherwise, the hint is silently ignored.

[Markdown Editing Help](/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) doesn't currently document this requirement.