# Syntax highlighting for Python not working properly

Tags: bug, code-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python's “//” operator treated as a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81906/pythons-operator-treated-as-a-comment)

I noticed in one of the answers to my question

[How to iterate over Unicode characters in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7494064/how-to-iterate-over-unicode-characters-in-python-3)

that the automatic formatting is broken. It does seem to be correctly recognizing the language as Python, judging by the highlighted keywords, but it seems to be under the impression that // is a comment instead of a division operator. Perhaps something in the system hasn't been fully updated to Python 3?

(Sorry, there's probably some proper way to link to another question, but I couldn't figure it out so I just pasted the URL.)

Comment: I think all syntax stuff has been outsourced to google prettify, for which an upstream change is necessary to fix this ...