# Fix for $# code color highlight

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting, code

I am a Perl coder and I would like to ask Stack Overflow to fix code color highlights for `#` comments.

It works properly for real comments, such as

```
# this is a comment
```

but when `$#` is in code, such as

```
print $#variable;
```

it should not be highlighted as comment, but as a code.

I believe it is pretty easy fix. Can be that done?

Comment: SO uses an external library for syntax highlighting. In the past they have been indifferent to these requests (eg: "not our problem"). See also: [Python's “//” operator treated as a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81906/pythons-operator-treated-as-a-comment)

Comment: I vaguely recall that we're using Google's Syntax Highlighter library, so it's not really ours to fix. But don't quote me on that.

Comment: Faq entry stating the use of [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/172936

Comment: @Lix - you don't have to delete your comments - we know you like **stackoverflow** users :)

Comment: Felt it was just noise :P

Comment: For a moment there I thought that the title was the censored form of abusive language seen in comics #%$&$% and the like :P

Comment: @Manishearth - maybe Google thought the same when this issue was reported and that is why no fix was released for this issue :P

Comment: @stack $&$#%€£ Google.

Comment: are you using `<!-- language: perl -->` above the code-blocks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, Stack Exchange uses [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for its highlighting purposes, so typically bug reports should be directed at the project, and if they're addressed, they'll be pulled into the version used here.

Your specific case has actually [already been reported](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=162&q=perl), though no action has been taken on it. The Perl lexer is also handled by the common language lexer setup in `prettify.js`, so I'm not sure that this would be an easy fix without pulling it out (or hackily adding a Perl-specific flag for this use case).

Comment: Oooh... Google sucks!