# Perl syntax highlighting off with $" assignment

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fix for $# code color highlight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128143/fix-for-code-color-highlight)

Hopefully this is the right way to report this.  I poked around the long syntax highlighting questions for a while and couldn't find anything better.

Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10278888/1062461), it's clear that the syntax highlighter gets a bit confused. Obviously that's easy to understand, but I figured I should report it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To [quote myself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128143/fix-for-code-color-highlight/128144#128144):

> Stack Exchange uses [Google Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for its highlighting purposes, so typically bug reports should be directed at the project, and if they're addressed, they'll be pulled into the version used here.

In this particular case there doesn't seem to be an [open bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list) related to the `$"` variable, though it's (likely) a fairly similar issue to the one [linked from my other answer](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=162&q=perl).

The project maintainer was [fielding suggestions for a simple Perl grammar](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=57#c1) at one point to pull the Perl pieces out from the common language lexer and reduce Perl-specific errors like this, but it doesn't seem like anyone provided anything at the time.

Comment: Awesome.  Sorry I didn't find that before.  I submitted a new bug report because the rest of the perl-related reports on that site were a bit specific to `#` characters and quote operators for me to feel right just tacking on another comment.