# Why is syntax highlighting not working for my Perl script?

Tags: bug, status-declined, syntax-highlighting

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35536286/benchmarking-in-basex-how-to-set-up) I added a perl script. This script *works* and is correctly highlighted in all the editors that I tested in. Yet still highlighting doesn't seem to work as expected on SO. From this line and onward, all text is red.

```
my ($treebank) = $tline =~ /<tb>(.+)<\/tb>/;
```

I thought I had an error in my regex, but I have tested this thoroughly and can't find any errors.

I did make sure that SO interpreted the code as Perl by adding this definition above my snippet:

```
<!-- language: perl -->
```

And I'd assume the highlighter is smart enough to detect that scripts starting with this line are Perl scripts.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

So where did I go wrong? I did find [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130113/187614), but I just want to be sure I didn't make any foolish error.

Comment: Looks like a bug on the Prettify side itself, can't see anything wrong, though I'm not familiar with perl syntax myself.

Comment: please read the syntax highlighting FAQ http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/156631

Comment: Think I found the bug report: https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/209 /cc @m0sa can't SE team prod someone to fix that, though?