# Syntax highlighting for XPath

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I just answered a question on SO and was wondering about the syntax highlighting. As you can see at [Xpath - get maximum attribute for each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893410/xpath-get-maximum-attribute-for-each-element/16893827#16893827) the syntax highlighting for XPath goes wrong, obviously because `//` is interpreted as a comment.

I saw the page at [Changes to syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72082/changes-to-syntax-highlighting) and the list provided at http://pastebin.com/AWMtu5rK, which says that `xpath` should map to `lang-xml`. However, it would be rather strange to have `//` interpreted as a comment in XML as it is no valid comment.

So I was wondering whether the Google Code Prettify is the cause of the problem or the mapping in general or in this particular case is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of mappings you list to is inaccurate, I suppose it went through some changes since it was posted.

As Jeff says [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81908/138650), "webby" languages such as Python are mapped to the default syntax highlighting (the page you link to says it's mapped to `lang-py` which is not true today). The same seems to be true for `xpath` which is mapped to `default`. You can see this by checking the CSS class associated with the code block, which is `default` and not `lang-xml`.

You can [override](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81970/138650) the default by putting `<!-- language: lang-xml -->` before the code block.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. However, I would consider mapping `xpath` to `default` a bug and instead map it to `xml` automatically as it is done for `xquery`. First, because XPath is a subset of XQuery, so it seems reasonable and secondly, because currently xml does no syntax highlighting for XPath/XQuery, which is still better and less confusing than an incorrect syntax highlighting.